# C# Windows not opening on top

Tags: c#, winforms

Relates to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132297/c-windows-not-opening-on-top).

In my previous question I asked why my dialogs seem to be opening behind other windows. (Other windows not necessarily belonging to my program, e.g. Excel, Windows Explorer, etc.)

I was told to use the overloaded `ShowDialog()` and pass the parent as a parameter.

That's fine, and I've replaced all the ShowDialog()s with the overload.

However I still had the same problem here:

```
static class Program
{
  /// <summary>
  /// The main entry point for the application.
  /// </summary>
  [STAThread]
  static void Main()
  {
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    ofd.ShowDialog(); // First dialog

    // Do some stuff here...

    SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
    sfd.ShowDialog(); // Second dialog;
  }
}
```

In this example (don't comment on the code - I just wrote it up as a simple example), the user double-clicks the executable with several windows on their screen. The OFD appears on top, and the SFD appears underneath everything.

I usually have this sort of OFD/SFD set up in my simple programs which accept CSV or XLS files and do some simple processing of them. In this case, I put the OFD code in the static Main() method and load the dialog if no parameters were passed to the exe.

Comment: Doesn't dialogs need a parent window to be shown?  You don't have any windows here so you shouldn't expect everything to behave as you would expect.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666580/how-can-i-set-topmost-at-the-savefiledialog-using-c/4709536#4709536 Have you tried this? :)

Comment: I think you need Application.Run as an umbrella to keep to message pump going between forms.  Otherwise you lose focus when your first form exits and stops handling messages.

Comment: @Vimvq1987 I am trying to avoid TopMost if possible.

Comment: @shsmith I think you might be right, however it seems a shame to needlessly complicate such a simple program as described in my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modal Dialog boxes aren't meant to be used this way, although there's nothing stopping you from doing it anyway.

You must have an `Application.Run` as shsmith said.

For the simple example you gave in the question I would have a small window show up with a progress bar and/or rolling log status text.

Answer (score 13):

There is an other - I think the easiest - solution:

```
        ofd.ShowDialog(new Form() { TopMost=true });
```

It opens a new form, that will be immediately disposed, but it will give TopMost property to your ofd. You can give more properties like "TopLevel":

```
        ofd.ShowDialog(new Form() { TopMost=true, TopLevel=true });
```

Answer (score 4):

c# console application folder browser dialog TopMost
c# console application open file dialog TopMost

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var threadFolderBrowserDialog = new Thread(voidFolderBrowserDialog);
        threadFolderBrowserDialog.IsBackground = true;
        threadFolderBrowserDialog.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        threadFolderBrowserDialog.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Запуск выбора папки и файла в новом потоке");

        bool Exit = false;
        while (!Exit)
        {
            var exit = Console.ReadLine() == "exit" ? Exit = true : Exit = false;
            Console.WriteLine("Выход из программы по команде exit");
        }
    }
    [STAThread]
    static void voidFolderBrowserDialog()
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        if (fbd.ShowDialog(new Form() { TopMost = true, WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized }) == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(fbd.SelectedPath);
        }
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (ofd.ShowDialog(new Form() { TopMost = true, WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized }) == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ofd.FileName);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This solves my problem, in particular ```fbd.ShowDialog(new Form() { TopMost = true, WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized })```

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like the following (somewhat hacky):

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Form dummyForm = null;

        // Create a 'pseudo' invisible form that we make temporarily topmost
        dummyForm = new Form() { ShowInTaskbar = false, WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized };
        dummyForm.Show();
        dummyForm.TopMost = true;
        dummyForm.TopMost = false;

        // Use the dummy form as our parent
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.ShowDialog(dummyForm); // First dialog

        // Do some stuff here...

        SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
        sfd.ShowDialog(dummyForm); // Second dialog;
    }
}
```

The form gives you the possibility to use ShowDialog with a parent window handle, and the trick of starting it minimized overcomes the main issue of modifying the visibility of the form directly (which can lead to the form's window handle not being created).

Comment: I would not call this "_somewhat_ hacky".

Comment: You could also try messing about with SetWindowsPos() via p/invoke, although getting the windows handle is more than ugly, some ideas could probably be found here: [link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/OpenFileDialogEx.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I know you want to avoid topmost but you could try setting it and then unsetting it immediately after.  I did this in one of my apps and it worked ok for me.

Comment: Yes, this is potentially a solution but as I commented in a deleted answer, ShowDialog() is blocking and Open/SaveFileDialogs don't have a TopMost property.